# Is there any way to filter out the images taken by this very device rather than synced from icloud?

Tags: icloud, photos

I have an old iPhone 7 Plus (iOS 15.7), but after turning on iCloud, thousands of photos were syncing in (and saved locally on this iPhone 7 Plus).

Is there any way to filter out the photos taken by this very device?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, using a Mac:

1. Set Photos app on a Mac to also sync to iCloud.
2. If everything is synced, select all, then File→Export→etc. Put them in an otherwise empty directory (dir)
3. Install [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) if you don't already have it
4. `exiftool -csv -r -Directory -Filename -HandlerVendorID -LensID \`
   `-LensInfo -LensMake -LensModel -Make -Model (dir) > tempfile.csv`
5. Open tempfile.csv in a spreadsheet
6. Use the appropriate columns to sort the images you want to the top.
7. Use Directory & Filename from those rows to make a script that moves or copies those images to another directory.

Comment: If you want to put them back on the iPhone without any others, that's an equally complicated procedure, but if you need it, I'll post it.